# Script to extract a zip password in Full ASCII with control characters (0-31 range)

Tags: character-encoding, passwords, unzip, non-ascii-characters, control-characters

1. Suppose my **foo.zip** is encrypted with a password containing extended and control ASCII.
2. Its password in hex format is e.g. something like **9E6A01D15774FF**
3. I have made a password.txt by editing its hex to match my password, so it will look like this when opening with a text editor: �j�ÑWtÿ
4. I have no programming skills (!!!)

Problem is: I found no way to tell a zip extractor to read a binary password. I even tryed creating a simple script and editing its hex in the password part, so it looks like this

```
#!/bin/bash
unzip -P �j�ÑWtÿ /home/john/foo.zip
```

But stdin will always try to represent the non-printable characters and fails to pass the correct binary password to unzip.

My question is: Can you point me out a way to write a simple script (javascript?) that can extract zip files and supports full ascii passwords? (Please, remember I don't have any clue and my knowledge is very basic)

I know I may have made a stupid question, since nobody will want to include control characters in their password, but I'm stuck for a week in trying to figure this out. I would really appreciate your help!

Comment: You can hex-encode strings in the shell like so `echo $'\x74\x65\x73\x74'` outputs `test`

Comment: Thanks Alex but I've already tried both with echo and printf. Your solution works great for ASCII > 31 range, the problem is with non printable characters. There was no way the stdin could pass the right binary input as password